# Show more and less option with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a paragrap in which if line is more than 3 then it should show "Show more option" and if i click on it it will expand the paragraph and "Show less option should display."If i CLick on show less thenit will collapse the paragraph.
I have to do it with bootstrap only no jquery and javascript.

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Bootstrap doesn't have a control like that built-in … and if it did it would use JavaScript with the jQuery library to build it.

Comment: I have make the paragrap line height 1rem and total height 3 rem for 3 line.I have set the overflow property hidden.If i click on show more link then it should show the overflow text.

Comment: you can do this with `js` by toggling between the values of overflow property

Answer (score 2):

you can perform the effect using `javascript` and `jquery` you need to do something like this;
[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cemra1v2/1/)

```js
   

 $("document").ready(function(){
        // find elements
    var banner = $("#banner-message")
    var button = $("button")
    // when first load the window
    if($('.option').length>3){
    
    $('.option').each(function(index){
    var option=$(this);
    if(index>2){
    option.toggleClass('hidden');
    }
    })
    }
    
    // handle click and add class
    button.on("click", function(){
     if($('.option').length>3){
    
    $('.option').each(function(index){
    var option=$(this);
    if(index>2){
    option.toggleClass('hidden');
    }
    });
    }
    });
    });
```

```css
body {
    background: #20262E;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
  }
  
  #banner-message {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  button {
    background: #0084ff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  #banner-message.alt {
    background: #0084ff;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  
  #banner-message.alt button {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
  }
  
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

body {
    background: #20262E;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
  }
  
  #banner-message {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  button {
    background: #0084ff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  #banner-message.alt {
    background: #0084ff;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  
  #banner-message.alt button {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
  }
  
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner-message">
        <div class='option'> option1</div>
         <div class='option'> option2</div>
          <div class='option'> option3</div>
           <div class='option'> option4</div>
      
        <button>Change color</button>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```